# Reusing a $_GET variable in a $_POST?

Tags: php, mysql

I have my index.php page that sends values over to edit.php via $_GET/html link.  I can see the values go, including the table ID I want to use using echo statements. The problem is that I need the specific ID value used in another form using a submit form($_POST).  I've tried different approaches including SESSION, making the $ID = $_GET....  I'm pulling my hair out.

Here is the order of things:

```
//Edit link on index.php sends the id='summary_id', which works
<td align="center"><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['summary_id']?>">Edit</a></td>

//Edit.php grabs the variable and I set it to that variable
if(isset($_GET['id']))
echo "<pre>Value of GET \$_GET:</br>";print_r($_GET);echo"</pre>";  
    {
        $summary_id = $_GET['id'];
        $summary_id = $_POST['summary_id'];
```

But, when I try to use $summary_id in a form (using $_POST this time), I get no value.  I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is "legal".  I've tried sending the summary_id as a hidden value in the form, but again, nothing is going through.  I'm losing it after that initial  $_GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong.You are overwriting the variable that is not available `$_POST['summary_id']`

if you really want to use post method use this

```
<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['summary_id'];?>" name="summary_id"/>
<input type="submit" value="EDIT"/>
</form>
```

or you can use `header()` to post the value

Comment: Thanks again!  I have some work to do, but this way is much cleaner and exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your own variable. Also, it's clear from this that you don't actually have PHP errors turned on.

Comment: Thank you, I think?  What's clear to you may not be clear to me, which is why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) instead as it contains both $_GET and $_POST.